# Scrape data from a highchart using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, highcharts

I am trying to scrape data from a website which is on a highchart,I have tried to use class names and it always prints an empty list

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/MR NAT ASS/Downloads/chromedriver')
driver.get("https://www.statsbots.org.bw/motor-vehicle-accident-trend-transport-sector")
data = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//g[@class="html not-front not-logged-in no-sidebars page-node 
page-node- page-node-105 node-type-easychart mean-container"]')

year_stats = []
for p in range(len(data)):
year_stats.append(data[p].text)

years = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//g[@class="highcharts-axis-labels highcharts-xaxis-labels"]')

year_list = []
for s in range(len(years)):
year_list.append(years[s].text)

print(year_stats)
#####
print(year_list)
```

Any suggestions please

Comment: here is the website https://www.statsbots.org.bw/motor-vehicle-accident-trend-transport-sector

Comment: Check if you can get the JSON values in the page and look for `window.easychart` = it contains the data used for generate the chart. Also, browse http://cb.botswana.opendataforafrica.org/nanhvtg/national-summary-data-page-nsdp and check if the data is available through requests.

Answer (score 1):

All charts are stored in global variable `Highcharts`. You can get series data for a specific chart by running the below JS code:

```
Highcharts.charts[2].userOptions.series[0].data;
```